# Checkbox state is not updating in RCP

Tags: eclipse-rcp, rcp

I am beginner of RCP framework.In this one of Editor I have made one SWT table with SWT.Check Table item. I have facing problem regarding check box selection.

ReloadView() function trigger at a certain interval and fetch database changes and trying to change data but its not reflecting in view. Debug the code and found there is no data issue but its not updating existing table/selection.

```
private static final Button[] checkBoxButton = new Button[size]; 
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) 
{
        toolkit = new FormToolkit(parent.getDisplay());
        compositeObj = toolkit.createComposite(parent, SWT.NONE);
        GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();
        compositeObj.setLayout(layout);
        GridData gridData = new GridData();
        gridData.verticalAlignment = GridData.FILL;
        gridData.horizontalSpan = 4;
        gridData.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
        gridData.grabExcessVerticalSpace = true;
        gridData.horizontalAlignment = GridData.FILL;
        Button button = new Button(compositeObj, SWT.PUSH);
        button.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.BEGINNING, SWT.CENTER, false, false));
        button.setText("  Test  ");
        btsViewer = new TableViewer(compositeObj, SWT.SINGLE  | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL |  
        SWT.FULL_SELECTION| SWT.BORDER ); 
        btsViewer.getControl().setLayoutData(gridData);
        final int[] bounds = { 30, 80};
        for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++)
        {
            TableViewerColumn viewerColumn  = new TableViewerColumn(btsViewer, SWT.NONE);
            final TableColumn column = viewerColumn.getColumn();
            column.setText(titles[i]);
            column.setWidth(bounds[i]);
            column.setResizable(true);
            column.setMoveable(true);
            column.pack();
        }
        table = btsViewer.getTable();
        table.setHeaderVisible(true);
        table.setLinesVisible(true);
        for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++)
            new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
        ReloadView(parent);
}

public final static void ReloadView(Composite parent) {
        int Count = 0;
        dataProvider = SqlData.collectDetails();
        if (dataProvider.size() != 0) {
            for (DataProvider data : dataProvider) {
                Trigger(parent, data.sTemp, data.bstate, Count);
                Count++;
            }
        }
}
public final static void Trigger(Composite parent, String sTemp, Boolean bstate, final int Index){
    TableItem[] items = table.getItems();
    Label propertyLabel = null;

    editor[index] = new TableEditor(table);
    checkBoxButton[index] = toolkit.createButton(table, "   ", SWT.CHECK);
    checkBoxButton[index].pack();
    checkBoxButton[index].setSelection(bstate);
    editor[index].grabHorizontal = true;
    editor[index].setEditor(checkBoxButton[index], items[index], 0);
        
    editor[index] = new TableEditor(table);
    propertyLabel = toolkit.createLabel(table, sTemp, SWT.CENTER);
    editor[index].grabHorizontal = true;
    editor[index].setEditor(propertyLabel, items[index], 1);
}
```

Comment: If you use TableViewer you should not create TableItems in your code - the TableViewer expects to do that. For TableViewer you use a Content and Label Provider and setInput. If you want to stick with TableItems just use Table.

Comment: Hi greg-449,Thanks for reply. As suggestion replaces TableViewer to Table & TableItems not my checkbox is working fine. Ist I dont have much understanding of first approach i.e Content and Label Provider give me any link to explore more.2nd i have to show Progress bar in one column is it possible with table and tableItems?

Comment: [Introduction to the JFace Table Viewer API](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJFaceTable/article.html)